# Using Registration-Free COM Interop with a C# .NET DLL without codebase/GAC?

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, sxs, registration-free-com

I have a C# .NET DLL that is exposed through COM Interop for which I have generated a manifest file. The DLL is being consumed through an Excel VBAProject using `CreateActCtx` and `CreateObject` to create my objects.

Everything works fine, however... I need to call `regasm MyProject.dll /codebase` or register with GAC. Otherwise I get `ActiveX component can't create object` or `error in dll` errors.

Is it possible to use a .NET DLL without having to register the DLL at all? I was able to do this previously with a VB6-based DLL and a manifest file.

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible. The instruction are a little long so I'm just going to supply an MSDN link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @Jac that's a good article but it doesn't cover a native client using a managed server, which is the OP's question. Are there any extra steps for that situation?

Comment: I have no experience doing this so I don't know what "gothchas" you could run into. Just that I have read plenty of times it can be done. I found this post on SO specifically for Excel VBA. Possibly this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707499/can-i-use-regfree-com-with-an-application-written-in-excel-vba

Comment: @jac I've read that SO post as well. Reg-Free COM works fine with a VB6 DLL, but stops working as soon as .NET DLL is used. I've followed the SideBySide example with limited luck. I can get it to work if I call `regasm /tlb SideBySide.dll` on my computer but as soon as it runs on another it gives the same "can't create object" error.

Comment: Try posting your manifest files.